# How can two coupled Scala generic type constructors refer to each other as type parameters?

Tags: generics, scala, scala-2.8, scala-java-interop

In Java 1.6.0_21, the first example below compiles fine, and I think that's because the parameter type bounds are bare.  That is, in the "Z extends Zen" bound below, Java allows 
Zen to slide by as the name of a raw, non-generic type (equivalent to the runtime "erased"
type).  This might be wrong and bad, but it also can be useful, or at least wacky 
good times on the bus ride home:

```
public class CorefTest {

    public static interface Tao<Z extends Zen> {
    }

    public static interface Zen<T extends Tao> {
    }
}
```

In Scala 2.8.0.final, the below compiles great up through CleanOceanWithFish, showing 
some basic type param hookups.  But when we get to Zen and Tao being interdependent 
generic types, the Scala compiler rejects my weaving construct.   See compiler errors in comments.

```
package heaven.piece
class Lucky {
    trait Water {}
    trait CleanWater extends Water {}
    trait Sea [W <: Water] {}
    trait Fish[S <: Sea[CleanWater]] {}

    trait CleanOceanWithFish[F <: Fish[CleanOceanWithFish[F]]] 
                   extends Sea[CleanWater]{}

// Above code compiles fine, but the type constructor pair below doesn't compile 

    trait Tao[Z <: Zen[Tao[Z]]]{};

    trait Zen[T <: Tao[Zen[T]]]{};
}
// error: type arguments [Lucky.this.Tao[Z]] do not conform to trait Zen's 
//     type parameter bounds [T <: Lucky.this.Tao[Lucky.this.Zen[T]]]

// error: type arguments [Lucky.this.Zen[T]] do not conform to trait Tao's 
//     type parameter bounds [Z <: Lucky.this.Zen[Lucky.this.Tao[Z]]]
```

So, how can I properly tie the Scala (2.8.0) knot between Tao and Zen?

It's certainly a contrived example, but what I really want is to use Scala to extend
some real Java types I have working in the above form (which existential types via "forSome" and "[_]" are not helping me with, so far).  I think that getting Zen and Tao 
compiling in Scala will probably show the way to that Java extension.  If you can consider the Java extension issue in your answer, so much the better.   Thanks for any help!

**Update** posted after the very helpful first two answers below from Nikita S. and Kris N.

I empirically learned some more about various Java+Scala coreference scenarios.  The upshot is that when we want interoperable coreferent types in *both* Java and Scala, then this Java construct:

```
public static interface JavaFunTao<JFZ extends JavaFunZen<? extends JavaFunTao<JFZ>>> {
    public JFZ consider(JFZ someZen, JavaFunTao<JFZ> otherTao);
}
public static interface JavaFunZen<JFT extends JavaFunTao<? extends JavaFunZen<JFT>>> { 
    public JFT meditate(JFT someTao, JavaFunZen<JFT> otherZen);
}
```

provides more specific typing than my first Java example at top (avoiding the raw types), and is then properly extensible in Scala as follows:

```
class HiFunTao[HFZ <: HiFunZen[  _ <: HiFunTao [HFZ]]] extends JavaFunTao[ HFZ] {
    override def consider(someZen: HFZ, otherTao: JavaFunTao[HFZ]) : HFZ = {
        println (this.toString() + " is considering " + someZen + " and " + otherTao);
        someZen
    }
}
class HiFunZen[HFT <: HiFunTao[ _ <:  HiFunZen [HFT]]] extends JavaFunZen[ HFT] {
    override def meditate(someTao: HFT, otherZen: JavaFunZen[HFT]) : HFT = {
        println (this.toString() + " is meditating on " + someTao + " and " + otherZen);
        someTao
    }
}
```

I verified that we can make simple concrete types based on these, instantiate them, and invoke their methods.  The key step in both the Java and the Scala is placing the bounded wildcard at the point where the type parameter tree loops back into the current declaration type, i.e. the "? extends" in java, and the "_ <:" in Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since neither Zen nor Tao are covariant, there's a substitutability problem in your zen and tao. This compiles fine for me under 2.8.1:

```
trait Tao[+Z <: Zen[Tao[Z]]]

trait Zen[+T <: Tao[Zen[T]]]
```

Of course, if you want to meditate on Z or T then this is also not going to work for you, at least not exactly as stated because of the issue of having a covariant type parameter in a contravariant position. You can get around that problem like this:

```
trait Tao[+Z <: Zen[Tao[Z]]] {
  def meditate[M >: Z](m: M) = ()
}

trait Zen[+T <: Tao[Zen[T]]] {
  def meditate[M >: T](m: M) = ()
}
```

but this may still produce constraints on your implementation that you may not want. It's confusing, at the least. :)

**Update:**

This also, by the way, avoids the problem mentioned in the update of NSkvortsov's answer. This compiles fine:

```
class Zazen extends Zen[Tao[Zazen]]
```

Comment: Great solution! Never thought covariance can help )

Comment: Yes Kris Nuttycombe, your original answer about covariance is a big
help! I think I now understand the substitutability problem for the 
Scala traits, and why the covariance annotation fixes it.  Your note
on method contravariance is helpful, too.  All your code compiles 
from me on 2.8.1.    

In your update, are you saying that you think the Java types should
in fact be extendable from Scala, using the Zazen technique (this doesn't work for me, yet)?  Or do you agree with NSkvortsov's update:  Extending the java types in Scala is impossible due to the raw types issue?

Comment: Oops, I missed that NSkvortsov was talking about Scala extending Java. I'm sure that the problem of extending the Java type is soluble, because I've had to do it once before, but now I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. :P

Comment: I've tried extending Java using covariance - and it does not work. I think the original task of extending Java interfaces with raw type generics can not be solved.

Answer (score 2):

I think, this is what you need:

```
class MyClass {

  trait Tao[Z <: Zen[_]]{};
  trait Zen[T <: Tao[_]]{};

}
```

This snippet successfully compiled by Scala 2.8.1

**Update**

Unfortunately, extending `CorefTest.Zen` and `CorefTest.Tao` in scala is impossible. Here is why.

The only way to implement interfaces in **java** is to use *raw types*:

```
public class TaoImpl<Z extends CorefTest.Zen> implements CorefTest.Tao<Z> { }

public class ZenImpl<T extends CorefTest.Tao> implements CorefTest.Zen<T> { }
```

than one can instantiate classes like this:

```
TaoImpl<ZenImpl> tao = new TaoImpl<ZenImpl>();
ZenImpl<TaoImpl> zen = new ZenImpl<TaoImpl>();
```

But **scala** *does not support raw types*. So `TaoImpl` and `ZenImpl` just can not be defined.
Please see this [e-mail thread](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Implement-a-raw-type-td2252733.html) and issues [#2091](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2091) and [#1737](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/1737) for detailed discussion

Comment: Thank you, yes, that compiled for me in 2.8.0.  So then I tried adding a method using Z to your Tao:  
  
def meditate(z : Z) : Unit = {
  println("meditating on: " + z);
}

and I get a compiler OutOfMemory error, indicating the same kind of desire from the compiler to recursively dig deeper into my types that prompted the original inquiry.

Comment: Very strange. I tried adding a method, checked both 2.8.0 and 2.8.1 script and compile mode - everything works just fine. Here is Tao code: `trait Tao[Z <: Zen[_]]{   def meditate(z: Z): Unit = { println("meditating on " + z); }  };`

Comment: Thanks again NSkvortsov !  I updated to Scala 2.8.1. and now the "meditate" method compiles.  OK, so I think this is a decent way to get an equivalent of the (sloppy) functionality  we have in Java.

However, my original real problem (hinted at in bottom of my question) is unsolved because the [_] technique doesn't work to extend co-referent generic java types in Scala.  I may pose that as a separate question, but meanwhile can someone state what is illegal about my original pair of more tightly woven Scala type constructors, which still give same errors under 2.8.1?    Спасибо otra vez!

Comment: Thank you NSkvortsov, the additional references on Scala's limititations with raw types are very helpful!